# How do I debug PhoneGap Javascipt App on ios?

Tags: ios, debugging, phonegap-build, phonegap

I run the latest Ubuntu on my laptop and I've built this mobile app using Javascript,HTML and PHP/MySQLi. My editor of choice is Visual Studio Code. I rent a Mac from the guys at Mac In Cloud. My rental allowed me to get into the Apple Developer Account which allowed me to successfully get all my certificates and build the `ios.ipa`. I also have `android.apk`.

I need to mention I registered my client's `iphone UUID` in my developer account.

I have two Android phones on which I'm able to install and test the app. I use `Chrome Dev Tools Remote Debugging` for my Android Devices. So far so good.

I do not necessarily have access to an iphone, because my client lives in a different country, but, he does not mind spending some time on teamviewer so that I can debug the app if necessary.

Now I want to know, how can I debug the app on ios? What are my options here? I'd like to have access to a web console just like in Chrome or Firefox. That's what I'm used to.

I don't know nothing about Mac, Safari or Xcode but I don't mind learning for the sake of debugging, plus I do have access to a Mac. I just don't know how to go about this as it is my first time please be nice. What are the steps? Explain to me in layman terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this question. Works for me. So if you want to be able to truly see all the errors triggered by a physical device, you do need access to a physical phone and a mac.I had to borrow an actual iphone and a mac for this.

Following the [steps here](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html) helped me debug the app.